# To convert dropdown id to text to store in sql

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I want store text from dropdown which retrived from database,i am able to display in site

[image]

but now i am getting only id in sql DB.Please need suggestion

[image]

**View**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="email">Coachings:*</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MainCourseId, new SelectList(Model.MainCourseList, "Key", "Value"), "Select Main Course", new { @class = "form-control", required = "required" })</div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
MainCourse = request.MainCourseId.ToString()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by default Html.DropDownListFor() will send the selected option "value" to the controller...if you want to send the text, then give your course name as value.......

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MainCourseId, new SelectList(Model.MainCourseList, "CourseName", "CourseName"), "Select Main Course", new { @class = "form-control", required = "required" })
```